# How to keep two networkSecurityConfig from different libraries?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-network-security-config

I have an app that offers surveys to users. One of the partners is called [Bitlabs](https://bitlabs.ai/), and we can import their SDK with:

`com.github.BitBurst-GmbH.bitlabs-android-library:core:3.1.19`

Another partner that I use is [Pollfish](https://www.pollfish.com/). According to Pollfish [documentation](https://www.pollfish.com/docs/android/google-play), we should (optional) add a cleartext http traffic. Please refer to step **6.2** from the documentation. So far, so good. I create the XML file, and add the `android:networkSecurityConfig` to my Manifest.

The issue happens, when I try to build the project. It seems that the previous partner (Bitlabs) already does have an `android:networkSecurityConfig`, and building the project fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@networkSecurityConfig value=(@xml/domain_whitelist) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-62
    is also present at [com.github.BitBurst-GmbH.bitlabs-android-library:core:3.1.19] AndroidManifest.xml:15:18-78 value=(@xml/network_security_config).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-148:19 to override.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.manifest.ManifestHelperKt.mergeManifests(ManifestHelper.kt:125)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.manifest.ManifestHelperKt.mergeManifests$default(ManifestHelper.kt:46)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest.doTaskAction(ProcessApplicationManifest.kt:178)
...
```

According to the Exception, I can simply add the `tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"` to my application element on my Manifest, but as far as I understood, this will replace the Bitlabs `networkSecurityConfig`, right?

Is there any way to keep those two different configs? Maybe merge them or something?

Comment: The entry in AndroidManifest.xml is just a link to the XML file containing the actual config. Not sure what happens if you have two network security config XML files of the same name. If everything goes wrong you can still manually merge the content if all network security config files and specify it using the replace entry you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add the data from Bitlabs' `network_security_config.xml` file to your `domain_whitelist.xml`, and have the `<application` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```xml
<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/domain_whitelist"
    tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"
    ...>
```

Comment: I think this is the only way to go. But it has some drawbacks. For example, if in the future I add another partner with a networkSecurityConfig, I won't even notice it, because my networkSecurityConfig will replace the new SDK config and will not throw any errors. But it is what it is. Thank you for the answer.